# INSERT of data from a query into an existing table

Tags: python, sql

This query works…

```
SELECT Round(( (SELECT Count(*) 
                FROM   nps_surveys 
                WHERE  score >= 9 
                       AND social = 0 
                       AND Date(completedon) >= Last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + 
                                                INTERVAL 1 day 
                                                - INTERVAL 1 month) / 
                              (SELECT Count(score) 
                               FROM   nps_surveys 
                               WHERE  score IS NOT NULL 
                                      AND social = 0 
                                      AND Date(completedon) >= Last_day( 
                                          CURRENT_DATE) + 
                                                               INTERVAL 1 day 
                                                               - 
                                          INTERVAL 1 month) * 
                      100 ) - ( (SELECT Count(*) 
                          FROM   nps_surveys 
                          WHERE  score >= 0 
                                 AND score <= 6 
                                 AND social = 0 
                                 AND Date(completedon) >= Last_day(CURRENT_DATE) 
                                                          + 
                                                          INTERVAL 1 
                                                          day 
                                                          - INTERVAL 1 month) / 
                                      (SELECT Count(score) 
                                       FROM   nps_surveys 
                                       WHERE  score IS NOT NULL 
                                              AND social = 0 
                                              AND Date(completedon) >= Last_day( 
                                                  CURRENT_DATE) 
                                                                       + 
                                                                       INTERVAL 
                                                                       1 day 
                                                                       - 
                                                  INTERVAL 1 month) * 
                          100 )) nps;
```

But this one doesn’t…

```
SELECT cast(round(( 
                    ( 
                    SELECT Count(*) 
                    FROM   nps_surveys 
                    WHERE  score >= 9 
                    AND    social = 0 
                    AND    Date(completedon) >= Last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month) /
                   ( 
                          SELECT count(score) 
                          FROM   nps_surveys 
                          WHERE  score IS NOT NULL 
                          AND    social = 0 
                          AND    date(completedon) >= last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month)*100) - (
                  ( 
                         SELECT count(*) 
                         FROM   nps_surveys 
                         WHERE  score >=0 
                         AND    score <= 6 
                         AND    social = 0 
                         AND    date(completedon) >= last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month) /
                  ( 
                         SELECT count(score) 
                         FROM   nps_surveys 
                         WHERE  score IS NOT NULL 
                         AND    social = 0 
                         AND    date(completedon) >= last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + interval 1 day - interval 1 month)*100)) nps;
```

I keep getting an error when running of `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nps' at line 1`, but it doesn’t make sense because the only difference is the `cast` function. I tried inserting the known working query above  into my python script *without* the `cast` and it barks at me too.

Answer (score 1):

You should try simplify your query to something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN score >= 9 THEN 1 END) as bigger_9,           
       COUNT(CASE WHEN score >= 0 and score <= 6  THEN 1 END) as between_0_6,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN score = 0 THEN 1 END) as equal_0,
       COUNT(score) total_count // Dont need filter NULL, COUNT doesnt count NULL
FROM table
WHERE social = 0 
  AND date(completedon) >= last_day(CURRENT_DATE) + 
                           interval 1 day - interval 1 month*100
```

*not sure about the date part but hope you get the idea*

Answer (score 0):

You never used a corresponding closing parenthesis on the cast function.

Comment: When I open the parenthesis with `SELECT cast(...` and don't close it, I get an error of `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nps' at line 1`.

Comment: @JohnF That's my point exactly, you have indicated you are performing a function call with `cast(...` but you never close it - which is a syntax error as the message indicates.

Comment: @EyueIDK When I add the closing `)` such as `nps);`, it still returns an error.

Comment: @JohnF you need the closing parenthesis before `nps` not after.

Comment: Honestly not sure I even need the `cast` since I'm not converting the input to something else. Even if I remove it, the query will run as normal, but when I put it in my python script, the SQL error returns.

Comment: @JohnF I'm totally lost about your problem now. And secondly your aren't using the cast function properly, you need to specify the datatype you want to cast it to: `cast (expression AS datatype)`